# React Native display PDF in Android web view

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions, react-native-webview

I have a React Native app in which at some page I've got a web view (`react-native-webview`) for displaying PDFs from our server.

In iOS everything works fine, in Android, whenever I try to view the file I got:

`Cannot downoad files as permission was denined. Please provide permission to write to storage, in order to download files.`

I've then added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to my manifest. Now, I'm getting the following alert:

[image]

I think it's pretty scary and very stupid from a user experience perspective. I'm not accessing photos, media, or files, all I'm trying to do is to display a simple PDF inside a web view. I don't want my users to be presented such alert.

When I tap allow, it says `Downloading...` and downloads the PDF like a file that can be opened outside my app. I don't want this behavior, I want PDF to render inside web view just like iOS does.

How can I display PDFs in Android using React Native web view, without a scary dialog which has nothing to do with what I'm actually trying to do?

(I'm on React Native 0.59.9, Android 8.1, Android SDK 28, `react-native-web-view` 5.12.0)

Comment: I remember appending pdf urls to google doc viewer url in order to display them in RN webview on Android. Like so `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=<pdf-url-goes-here>`. Files getting downloaded could be because of `Content-Disposition: attachment` response header for pdf files. This header will force browser to download file first before allowing to view content.

Comment: related link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6488#issuecomment-291800918

Comment: @Amar some of the PDFs are on a server that require authentication, not sure if embedding them that way would work.

Comment: Documents behind an auth might make it tricky. In that case, if you don't need a general document viewer may be you can use a pdf only solution, something like [react-native-pdf](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf)

Comment: @Amar unfortunately I need a general document viewer. It can be HTML, PDF, or anything that a web view would normally open, may or may not be behind auth. I don't know the contents in advance, all I know is that I have the auth and it's a document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying various things I've given up on displaying PDFs directly and converting it to HTML. There's apparently no reliable way to display PDFs in default browser (viewing PDF directly *might* work on some machines but definitely not reliable as it didn't on my device/emulators).

Answer (score 0):

Observed this issue in  `"react": "17.0.2", "react-native": "0.66.3",` & i was using `react-native-webview`

- react-native-webview cannot directly allow pdf rendering, you can do work around, you can use gview [base_url][1] for that. 
    for example https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.elpregonero.info/PARTITURA/PDF/619%20-%20the%20beatles%20%20-%20something.pdf
- and then render it in webview as below 
  `import { WebView as Webs } from "react-native-webview";` 
  `<Webs originWhitelist={["*"]} allowFileAccess={true} allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true} source={{uri:`${your_base_url_mentioned_above}`}} style={styles.webViewer} //do not forget flex:1 in style />`
- In-order to make above mentioned hack to work, your url should have .pdf as extension
- if its not there then use another hack,
- download pdf from your url & then render it.
- inorder to do that you can use below packages
  `rn-fetch-blob` to download the file from url & then use `react-native-pdf` to render it(you have to get the path of the file & then you have to provide).
- but `rn-fetch-blob` is not maintained i guess, use some-other packages like `react-native-fs` to download the file.
- There is no way webview will handle pdf directly in android.